# can I send a message to a specific session using java websocket

Tags: java, java-websocket

I followed the following tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets.
I can send messages and all it is working as per expectation.
But is it possible to send a message only to a specific session? If yes, can you please guide me?

```
 @ServerEndpoint(value = "/endpoint/{username}", decoders = MessageDecoder.class, encoders = MessageEncoder.class)
public class ChatEndpoint {

    private Session session;
    private static final Set<ChatEndpoint> chatEndpoints = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();
    private static HashMap<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("username") String username) throws IOException, EncodeException {

        this.session = session;
        chatEndpoints.add(this);
        users.put(session.getId(), username);
        System.out.println(session.getId() + " xxx");
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setFrom(username);
        message.setContent("Connected!");
        broadcast(message);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, Message message) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        String userName = (String)session.getId();
        Iterator it = users.entrySet().iterator();
//        while(it.hasNext())
//        {
//            Map.Entry<String, String> me = (Map.Entry)it.next();
//            System.out.println("session id: " + me.getKey() + " values: " + me.getValue() + " " + userName);
//            if (users.containsValue("u0"))
//            {
//                break;
//            }
//        }
//        message.setTo(session.getId());
        message.setFrom(users.get(session.getId()));
        broadcast(message);
        System.out.println(message.getContent());
        
        
    }

    
    private static void broadcast(Message message) throws IOException, EncodeException {
//        for (ChatEndpoint ce : chatEndpoints)
//        {
//            if (ce.session.getId().equals(users.get("u0")))
//            {
//                ce.session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(message);
//            }
//        }
        chatEndpoints.forEach(endpoint -> {
            synchronized (endpoint) {
                try {
                    endpoint.session.getBasicRemote()
                        .sendObject(message);
                } catch (IOException | EncodeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I added the above code
Thank you

Comment: The whole point of a websocket is that you publish and it goes to all subscribers, you can either tack a client id onto the message so other subs know to ignore it, or just have a unique topic for that individual sub.

Comment: Can you guide me a little? It is for the 1st time when I playing with this. How can I have the individual topic?

Comment: If you look on the class Message on the tutorial you're following you find there are 2 attributes: _from_ and _to_. Those attributes can be used to send a message to a specific session, as you have a map that has session and users.

Comment: I changed the onMessage as below: 'code' @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, Message message) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        String userName = (String)session.getId();
        Iterator it = users.entrySet().iterator();

        message.setFrom(users.get(session.getId()));
        if (users.containsValue("u0")){
            message.setTo(users.get(session.getId()));
            broadcast(message);
            System.out.println(message.getContent());
        } 'code' but the same results